# Draft JS update EditorState from external script while maintaining undo/redo stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am using draft js and there I do have a situation that needs to put a new li element from another source of data.

I tried using the https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/493 approach that case I am able to add data but that also not retaining the undo/redo stack.
Is there a way I can maintain undo/redo stack?

```
function appendBlocksFromHtml(editorState, htmlString) {
  const newBlockMap = htmlToDraft(htmlString);
  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const blockMap = contentState.getBlocksAsArray();
  newBlockMap.contentBlocks = blockMap.concat(newBlockMap.contentBlocks);

  const newContentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(newBlockMap, contentState.getEntityMap());
  return EditorState.moveSelectionToEnd(EditorState.createWithContent(newContentState));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`appendBlocksFromHtml` what currently does is create new `EditorState` and returns.

We can retain old state while using `EditorState.push`

```
function appendBlocksFromHtml(editorState, htmlString) {
  const newBlockMap = convertFromHTML(htmlString);
  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const blockMap = contentState.getBlocksAsArray();
  newBlockMap.contentBlocks = blockMap.concat(newBlockMap.contentBlocks);
  const newContentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    newBlockMap,
    contentState.getEntityMap(),
  );
  return EditorState.moveSelectionToEnd(
    EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState, 'change-block-data'),
  );
}
```